# iOS SIGSEGV SEGV_ACCERR crash in layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, segmentation-fault

My app sometimes crashes in layoutSubview method. It happens when app calculate height for UITableViewCell. App crash sometimes, not always. Here functions code:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForEditorialCommentData:(EditorialCommentVMData *)editorialData
{
    EditorialCommentCell * cell = [EditorialCommentCell instanceCell];
    [cell applyViewModelData:editorialData];
    [cell layoutSubviews];
    return cell.commentTextLabel.frameBottom + kTextInsets.bottom;
}

+ (EditorialCommentCell *)instanceCell {
    static EditorialCommentCell *instance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"EditorialCommentCell" owner:0 options:0];
        instance = views[0];
        instance.frame = CGRectMake(instance.contentView.frame.origin.x,
                                        instance.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                        [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                                        instance.contentView.frame.size.height);
    });

    return instance;
}
```

Here is stack trace:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
 0  UIKit                          0x2ff92b3a -[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:] + 569
 1  UIKit                          0x2ff92cf5 __67-[_UIViewAdditiveAnimationAction runActionForKey:object:arguments:]_block_invoke + 408
 2  QuartzCore                     0x2f71e4c5 CA::Layer::end_change(CA::Transaction*, unsigned int, objc_object*) + 96
 3  QuartzCore                     0x2f71f06b CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool) + 530
 4  QuartzCore                     0x2f71ed87 -[CALayer setBounds:] + 110
 5  UIKit                          0x3017f84f -[_UILabelLayer setBounds:] + 58
 6  QuartzCore                     0x2f71fe01 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 600
 7  UIKit                          0x3017f7eb -[_UILabelLayer setFrame:] + 58
 8  UIKit                          0x2fcfc4d7 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 254
 9  UIKit                          0x2fd09f53 -[UILabel setFrame:] + 138
 CRASH->10 MYAPP                     0x000fb611 -[UIView(Frame) setFrameWidth:] (UIView+Frame.m:103)
 11 MYAPP                     0x00130c75 -[EditorialCommentCell layoutSubviews] (EditorialCommentCell.m:139)
 12 MYAPP                     0x001324ed +[EditorialCommentCell heightForEditorialCommentData:] (EditorialCommentCell.m:351)
 13 MYAPP                     0x00115733 -[EditorialCommentsViewModel applyDataFromItem:toVMItem:] (EditorialCommentsViewModel.m:298)
 14 MYAPP                     0x00114e73 -[EditorialCommentsViewModel vmDataFromItem:] (EditorialCommentsViewModel.m:222)
 15 MYAPP                     0x000fac29 -[FatherViewModel insertItemsUpdatingExisting:intoVMItems:] (FatherViewModel.m:418)
 16 MYAPP                     0x000f9cfd __39-[FatherViewModel updateItems:failure:]_block_invoke_3 (FatherViewModel.m:281)
 17 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a4718cb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
 18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a47ada3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 834
 19 libdispatch.dylib              0x3a47bcd7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
 20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3a5d2e31 _pthread_wqthread + 668
```

Here My layoutSubview code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; // Sometimes crashed here

    CGFloat contentLeft = kTextInsets.left;

    BOOL isReply = self.editorialCommentData.inReplyToCommentId != 0;

    if (isReply) {
        contentLeft += kAuthorLeftInset + self.authorImageView.frameWidth;
    }

    self.authorImageView.frameOrigin = CGPointMake(contentLeft, kContentInsets.top);

    self.votesLabel.frameWidth = 200; // Sometimes crashed here
    [self.votesLabel sizeToFit];

    self.votesLabel.frameTop = self.authorImageView.frameTop - 1.5f;
    self.votesLabel.frameRight = self.contentView.bounds.size.width - kContentInsets.right;

    <.....more code here.....>
}
```

I think it is memory management issue.

Comment: I don't know if it is related to your problem, but regarding the layoutSubviews method the Apple documentation said "You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I fixed it. From Marco comment about layoutSubviews method: "You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update."
I just changed layoutSubviews to layoutIfNeeded method:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForEditorialCommentData:(EditorialCommentVMData *)editorialData
{
    EditorialCommentCell * cell = [EditorialCommentCell instanceCell];
    [cell applyViewModelData:editorialData];
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell.commentTextLabel.frameBottom + kTextInsets.bottom;
}
```

From Apple documentation about layoutIfNeeded:

> Use this method to force the layout of subviews before drawing. Using
>   the view that receives the message as the root view, this method lays
>   out the view subtree starting at the root.